# How to remove systemd services

Tags: linux, systemd

If I install a new service then decide I don’t want that application anymore and delete it, the service is still listed in the output from `systemctl` as *error*.

Where is this coming from and how can I remove them thoroughly?

Answer (score 811, accepted):

My recipe for service obliteration (be careful with the `rm` statements!)

```
systemctl stop [servicename]
systemctl disable [servicename]
rm /etc/systemd/system/[servicename]
rm /etc/systemd/system/[servicename] # and symlinks that might be related
rm /usr/lib/systemd/system/[servicename] 
rm /usr/lib/systemd/system/[servicename] # and symlinks that might be related
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl reset-failed
```

It is possible that the systemd service 'wraps' the old style scripts in /etc/init.d, so you may want to clean that up too, but that is *not* where systemd services live.

Comment: Be aware that there are multiple locations where Systemd unit files are stored, notably `/usr/lib/systemd/system` and also  `/etc/systemd/system/`. For reference see: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/chap-Managing_Services_with_systemd.html#tabl-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Introduction-Units-Locations

Comment: I had also to remove `/etc/init.d/[servicename]` before running `systemctl reset-failed`

Comment: Right, I forgot to disable before removing the unit files. BTW, to find all unit files to remove, I inspect the output of `systemctl cat [servicename]`.

Comment: It may be a "wrapped" old style script in /etc/init.d/ but if you dont remove it you will find it still showing up under services left over from your removal.  I can tell you that was the case for me.  You could simply add that to your answer to make it more complete but hopefully the next person that needs it will look at the comments.

Comment: @Marlon - If your `/etc/init.d` service is still running after removing the wrapper service, then it is configured outside the narrow scope of this question (which is simply about systemd).  If you have sym links from `/etc/r c*` pointing to `/etc/init.d`, then you are not running systemd.

Comment: Why doesn't systemd provide a command to cleanup? Systemd knows how to cleanup after deleted *service and *.timer files. Why does systemd think users know the inner workings of the program???

Comment: You may need to unmask the service, if you had it masked before, to be able to disable it: `systemctl unmask [servicename]`

Comment: systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled will list all enabled services

Comment: @MarkLakata Why do we need to do `systemctl reset-failed` in the end?

Comment: I tried all of them, it does not work on ubuntu-16.04 LTS. On newer Linuxes, `systemctl reset-failed` is the key, but I had to give it multiple times, combined with some `daemon-reload`s. I am sorry to say, but I find it disastrous.

Comment: It's a good idea to make sure that there are no links to the deleted service in the directories `/etc/systemd/system/*.target.*`, although these *might* be cleaned up automatically.

Comment: I have some in: `./etc/systemd/user/` and `./etc/systemd/user/multi-user.target.wants/`

Comment: Anyone trying this might wanna run `find /usr/lib/systemd/system | grep "[servicename]"` and `find /etc/systemd/system | grep "[servicename]" to find any references to their service. My service was hiding in the subfolder `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/` and I don't know how many other subfolders exist for services.

Answer (score 94):

You are probably looking for `reset-failed`:

```
$ sudo systemctl reset-failed
$
```

From the systemd man page:

> `reset-failed [PATTERN...]`
>
> Reset the "failed" state of the specified units, or if no unit name
>              is passed, reset the state of all units. When a unit fails in some
>              way (i.e. process exiting with non-zero error code, terminating
>              abnormally or timing out), it will automatically enter the "failed"
>              state and its exit code and status is recorded for introspection by
>              the administrator until the service is restarted or reset with this
>              command.

Comment: That isn't what the question is asking for at all.  Why on earth has this been upvoted 17 times?

Comment: It sounds like this just resets the state for a service that should no longer exist. You should very likely delete the service files themselves, not simply change the state of a service you no longer want.

Comment: There are no service files to delete if it is a transient unit.

Answer (score 44):

Sounds like you uninstalled it, but didn't remove the systemd hook:

`# systemctl disable [servicename]`

Answer (score 18):

Adding on to [@mark-lakata](https://superuser.com/users/173246/mark-lakata)'s answer and keeping in mind the attentiveness required for the `rm` command. `[chkconfig]` can simplify the process!([click here to read about chkconfig](https://linux.die.net/man/8/chkconfig))

To re-iterate the list of commands:

1. `systemctl stop [servicename]`
2. `chkconfig [servicename] off` OR for newer systems `systemctl disable [servicename]`
3. `systemctl daemon-reload`
4. `systemctl reset-failed`

Note: 
The 1st command is optional depending on whether you want keep the service running in the present session or not (as for this question the command should be used).

The 2nd command takes care of both disabling and removing (following the symlinks) the service.

Comment: `chkconfig` was the original command to enable/disable SysVinit services. In systems using `systemd`, it may be present as a backward compatibility command; but the native `systemctl` command is just as simple: `systemctl disable [servicename]`

Comment: Okay, but the reason for me using this command is, you then don't have to explicitly run the rm command

Comment: chkconfig not found in ubuntu 16

Comment: `systemctl disable` is not removing the unit files for me

Answer (score 8):

A simple Oneliner could be:

```sh
service=YOUR_SERVICE_NAME; systemctl stop $service && systemctl disable $service && rm /etc/systemd/system/$service &&  systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl reset-failed
```

Set `service` to your desired service that should be deleted. E.g. `service=gunicorn.service`

Answer (score 6):

**Removing a service from systemd :**

Systemd uses unit (file to define services) to remove a service the unit have to be removed... here is a list of unit locations :

```
/etc/systemd/system/ (and sub directories)
/usr/local/etc/systemd/system/ (and sub directories)
~/.config/systemd/user/ (and sub directories)
/usr/lib/systemd/ (and sub directories)
/usr/local/lib/systemd/ (and sub directories)
/etc/init.d/ (Converted old service system)
```

**Refresh systemd :**

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl reset-failed
```

**Ghost services (not-found) :**

Systemd can list ghost (not-found) services even if the unit is deleted for many reasons

1. unit still present on one of the systemd directory
2. unit does not exit but a file link is still present on one of the systemd directory
3. the service is used in other unit(s)*

(*) if a service is mentioned in other unit but does not exist systemd will still list that service with the state not-found even if there is not unit file... you can search what unit is using that service with a text search and edit those units (not recommended if you plan to install that service later)

---

*Sources: [Linuxhacks.org](https://linuxhacks.org/how-to-remove-systemd-services/)

Disclosure: I am the owner of Linuxhacks.org*

Answer (score 4):

the best and official way to remove a service and its override files is:

```
systemctl revert servicename
```

this will delete anything created with:

- systemctl edit
- systemctl set-property
- systemctl mask

which will revert the given unit to its vendor configuration

Comment: This almost deletes everything; I had created a service with `systemctl edit --force --full exampleservice`, and `/etc/systemd/system/exampleservice.service` remained.