# Do I need a daemon-reload after stop, disable and removing the service file in systemd

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, systemd

I have a custom service. I recently ported it to systemd for RHEL7. I usually stop, disable and remove the service file. Is that enough or do I need to do these also

```
rm /etc/systemd/system/[servicename] symlinks that might be related
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl reset-failed
```

from:https://superuser.com/a/936976/82754

Comment: Why didn't you add this as a comment under [Mark](http://superuser.com/users/173246/mark-lakata)'s [answer](http://superuser.com/a/936976/82754)?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to stop, disable, and remove the service you should use `systemctl` commands like `systemctl stop [servicename]`, `systemctl disable [servicename]` and then `rm [path to service]`. You can also use `chkconfig` [check [here]](https://superuser.com/a/1344239/468159) command but as noted in one of my last answers by a user that this is now an old command and may not be available in newer systems!

Secondly, executing `systemctl daemon-reload` after the above is a good practice.

Lastly, executing `systemctl reset-failed` is not mandatory unless you have the service failed before. below is the systemd man page:

> reset-failed [PATTERN...]
>
> Reset the "failed" state of the specified units, or if no unit name is passed, reset the state of all units. When a unit fails in some way (i.e. process exiting with non-zero error code, terminating abnormally or timing out), it will automatically enter the "failed" state and its exit code and status is recorded for introspection by the administrator until the service is restarted or reset with this command.