# Found xmrig running on new server, is what I did to remove it enough?

Tags: ubuntu, malware

I saw my server's cpu usage was at 100%, so I investigated a bit and found Xmrig running.

This is a Vultr OpenLiteSpeed Django server. I had installed CyberPanel via the cyberpanel install script on their website that they email you, and had also only installed Django and a few other packages via pip, so I am assuming that the malware came from CyberPanel.

**I would like to know if the server could still be compromised after all of this?**

- `rm -rf /root/c3pool`

Following the advice here - https://superuser.com/a/936976

- `systemctl stop [servicename]`
- `systemctl disable [servicename]`
- `rm /etc/systemd/system/[servicename]`
- `rm /etc/systemd/system/[servicename] # and symlinks that might be related`
- `rm /usr/lib/systemd/system/[servicename]`
- `rm /usr/lib/systemd/system/[servicename] # and symlinks that might be related`
- `systemctl daemon-reload`
- `systemctl reset-failed`

When rebooting, the logs show nothing regarding the service trying to start, so it appears it is no longer on the system.

I then removed password authentication via ssh, and generated a gpg key on my local machine.

What else can I do to ensure the system is safe?

Comment: If only you had access to that server it is compromised. Nuke and restore a backup. Change all passwords. Update everything and check for known vulnerabilities.